# How to make DTO accept empty string fields but apply JPA validations if they're not empty?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to have a DTO validate the field input using validator annotations, but only if the fields in question are not empty strings in the request.

For example, I have a UserDto which takes a string username field that must have a length between 6 and 20. But I also want to make it possible for the request to send an empty string for this field.

Example request:

```json
{
  "username": "", // empty field won't be validated
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "password": "password123",
  etc...
}
```

Example entity:

```java
@Data
public class AdminUpdateUserDto {
    @Nullable
    @Length(min = 6, max = 20) // applies only if string isn't empty
    private String username;

    @Email
    @Length(min = 5, max = 30)
    private String email;

    @Length(min = 6, max = 20)
    private String password;
```

Is this possible without making a custom validator, or better said, within the Dto class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Min(6)
@Max(20)
@Pattern(regexp = "^$|.{6,20}"
```

**Note:** As @Mats stated you should remove Min and Max because it overrides Pattern. Thank you for the feedback Mats.

Comment: That's an ingenious solution, have you ever used something like this in production? Looks like maybe the way I want to do things is not the best. In NestJS I believe there is a more built-in solution with class-validator, something like @ValidateIf. I was wondering if there was something like that for JPA.

Comment: Hi, I personally did not try it but a friend of mine told me about it. So I thought it would be good to give it a try.

Comment: I'm currently using your solution and it works fine, though I had to take out the Min and Max annotations because they would override the Pattern. Thank you!